# Javascript get textContent of a div by his id console cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, html

Simple problem I guess, I have a simple div:

hello

I want to extract the text content, so I did:

```
document.getElementById("#test").textContent;
```

When I do that in the console, it tells me

> "Cannot read property 'textContent' of null".

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `id` of the div is `test`,in that case there is no need of hash `#`

```
document.getElementById("test").
```

will able to retrieve the element from the DOM